# i cant get fontface to work no matter what i do

Tags: css, font-face

im trying to upload a custom font from my pc using @font-face but its just not working no matter what ive tried. heres what i have currently in my style.css folder.

```
   <style>
@font-face {
    
    src: url(fonts/omori.ttf);
    font-family: 'omo' ;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
body {
  
  background-image:  url(removed for this question due to irrelevance and for privacy);
  color: grey;
   font-family:'omo';
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family:'omo';
}
</style>
```

please help me, i cant figure out what im doing wrong

Comment: Does the browser find the font file URL, or is there a 404 showing in the browser console?

Comment: I dont think you are going to be able to serve it from your PC.

Comment: What have you done to get the font loaded onto your server, what is the folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

What server are you using? Some servers are required additional configuration for such mime types.

Comment: the website hosting site im trying to do this on is neocities, but im testing everything in brackets.io aswell and it doesn't work in either of them.

Comment: Could  you please move "font-family: omo" in the @fon-face style to the top of the style scope?

Please make sure that your font name is "omo" or install it locally and get the name from font manager.